# Frank copula with no dependence

Tags: copula, multivariate-distribution

From Wikipedia, the Frank copula is the function $C(u, v)$ such that:

$$C(u, v) = \frac{1}{\theta} \log\!\left[ 1+\frac{(\exp(-\theta u)-1)(\exp(-\theta v)-1)}{\exp(-\theta)-1} \right]$$
for $\theta\in \mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$.

I am wondering whether there are alternate definitions such that the case where there is no dependence between the marginal distributions is covered? For example, make $C(u, v)$ continuous at $\theta = 0$ by setting $C(u, v) = uv$ if $\theta = 0$?

Comment: Taking the limit as $\theta\to 0^+$ is equivalent to your proposition.  You can demonstrate this by computing $C_\theta(u,v) = uv + O(u v \theta).$

Comment: @whuber I understand that taking the limit will do this. I guess I am wondering whether it is simply sufficient and clear to say $\theta= 0$ instead of invoking limits. Is there a reason why $\theta = 0$ is not included in the definition?

Comment: I suppose it depends on what $\kappa$ has to do with the question :-).  A mathematical stickler, as well as a naive reader, will object to not taking the limit; everyone else ought to be fine with setting $\theta$ to $0$--*once you have pointed out that this makes sense because it can be understood as a limit.*